# Using django to run python scripts with password arguments

Tags: python, django, subprocess, django-authentication

I need to create a web interface that will prompt for a username, password, and "record id" to run a separate python script using those credentials, and then spit back a generated file.

The separate script I wrote takes a username/password (and ID) to connect to an Oracle database (using cx_Oracle), gathers the relevant information, generates a PDF and saves it to a preset location. It spits out the location of the filename when it's done.

My thought was to create a django app that takes the following 3 parameters:

- Username
- Password
- ID  (this will be used to determine which records to fetch for the PDF)

Django will feed the parameters to the script by calling subprocess. I would put this into my view like so:

```
# ... 
import subprocess

# ...
def login_view(request):
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        record_id = request.POST.get('record_id')

        output = subprocess.check_output([
            "python", 
            "myscript.py", 
            "-id", 
            record_id, 
            "-u", 
            username, 
            "-p",
            password
        ])
        # The output will look like:
        # File /path/to/1234567.pdf saved
        fname = output.split(' ')[1]

        if fname.endswith('.pdf'):
            # Get the filename without the /path/to junk in front
            fname_nopath = fname.split('/')[-1]

            file = open(fname, 'rb')
            content = file.read()
            file.close

            response = HttpResponse(content, mimetype='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % fname_nopath

            return response
        else:
            response = HttpResponse(output)
            return response
```

I think this method is a little "clunky", and I would think there's a more elegant approach to take.

Another way I was thinking about would be to import the external script directly into my views.py file, then call its main function using the username, password, and record ID passed from django. This way I can avoid the subprocess machinery. If needed I can create a separate main() function in the script, have it return a filestring, and use that for both opening/serving the file through django.

The only problem is this interface is going to be used pretty frequently by users. To require them to login every time to generate a PDF report for each record_id is a bit of a pain. Ideally I would like to keep the users logged in (I think I would have to maintain a cx_Oracle cursor separately, and pass that into the script).

My feeling is that this is overcomplicating things. Is there a better way to do this or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should use django forms for handling user passed parameters.

2) You could save username/password in user's session- this way users won't need to enter them again.

3) This really depends on how much record id's you have, but you could show a list of available record id's by querying the database.

Comment: I ended up using django forms to take a username/password, then modified my original script so that I could import it directly into the view, parse the args, then run the main() function.